# Nodejs with JEST how to import using ES6 and relative path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-modules

I want to avoid this:

```
const SomeMethod = require('../shared/SomeMethod')
```

And instead use something more modern like this:

```
import { SomeMethod } from '/shared'
```

(under the hood): the `/shared` directory includes an index file of course, returning the object with the SomeMethod property which is also includes to a file.

As I am using JEST, I need two things to get around: 1 is that the node installed supports ES6 imports and 2 is that JEST will be familiar with relative path - notice that I have used the **/**shared so it means - go to the src directory and start from there.

But how to achieve this?

Comment: are you using babel?

Comment: I am using Parcel bundler for the app to work, it uses Babel under the hook. But please note that there is difference from the app to work to tests to work - tests are running by the JEST CLI which is probably configured different from the Parcel's built in config.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `babel`. According to the documentation of jest, you need to do the following

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and then create `babel.config.js` at the root of your project with the following content

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

You can look into the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) for more

[Here](https://medium.com/@saplos123456/using-es6-import-and-export-statements-for-jest-testing-in-node-js-b20c8bd9041c) is a step by step process of the same which is addressing the same problem

In order to use absolute path for Jest add the following line in `jest.config.js`

```
    module.exports = {
      moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
      ...
    };
```

here, `src` is considered as the root. You may need to change this one according to your folder name.

For more information you can follow this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understand-and-configure-absolute-import-paths-in-javascript-5cde3be2630d)

Comment: The ES6 module works, but the `'/shared'` doesn't working I should specify the absolute path instead of relative

Comment: @Raz yes you can try using the absolute path to be sure if the problem is with the path or not. Can you please share the error message?

Comment: Yes I have said that it works when I am using absolute path but not relative path.

Comment: That's good :) If the solution solves your problem please mark it as answer.

Comment: But I want to use relative path haha

Comment: Ok. So, what is happening when you are trying to use relative path?

Comment: Module not found... Try it by yourself, change the '../' to just '/'

Comment: Have you tried using `'../shared'`. If possible please try to give me a screenshot of folder structure

Comment: My friend using `'../'` means relative path. I want to use `'/'` which is absolute path to the base dir.

This is crucial to work because my files includes other files like that.

Comment: Still got error Cannot find module '/mod' from 'src/test.js' when doing `import Mod from '/mod'` but when doing `import Mod from './mod'` it works. I have put the mod.js file in the src dir. How to make it works?

Comment: Have you followed the article I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: It doesn't work what's written there and include many syntax errors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219745/discussion-between-raz-and-gypsycoder).